# Get all Google Map v3 markers loaded from GeoJSON

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geojson

I load data for my Google Maps v3 with GeoJSON:

```
that.map = new google.maps.Map($('#map')[0], mapOptions);
that.map.data.loadGeoJson('http://localhost/geoserver/...');
```

Now, at some point on some user event I need to get one marker and paint it blue.
I can set different color with [setIcon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Marker).

My idea is to get all features, then iterate through them, find the right feature (based on UNIQUE feature data field) and find marker behind that feature and change icon. I found some approaches that store all markers in array, but don't know why I need another array. Computer resources are important and I don't want to duplicate things.

I need help with, how to get features and how to get Marker object associated with selected feature. If there is a better way to do it, please...

**UPDATE**

I found this:

```
var feature = this.map.data.getFeatureById(ID);
```

I just need to get feature Marker. How? [Doesn't look that Feature class has method for that?](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Data.Feature)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no method/property that gives you access to the shape(marker,polygon,etc.) that has been created by the API.

To set a new icon-property for a particular feature use [`overrideStyle`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#override_default_styles):

```
map.data.overrideStyle(feature, {icon: newIconSettings});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is:

```
that.map.data.setStyle(function(feature) 
        {
            var color = 'red';
            if (feature.getProperty('color')) 
            {
                color = feature.getProperty('color');
            }
            return ({   // @type {google.maps.Data.StyleOptions}
                        icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/' + color + '-dot.png',
                    });
    });
```

But it is not as good as Dr. Molle solution, because it needs to iterate through entire features set. I found it on [google api documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer) (look for title Change Appearance Dynamically).